# Show that it is not possible to choose a uniform positive integer at random.

Tags: probability

In other words, we cannot define a probability measure on the positive integers that can be considered uniform.
A hint is given: What would be the probability of choosing a particular number?

Comment: And what would be the probability of choosing a particular number?

Comment: Well, positive integers are uncountable, I think, right? In other words, they're infinite, correct?

Comment: They are countably infinite, not uncountable, but what's important is that they are infinite.  So, what can you conclude from that?  Remember, that "uniform" means that they should each have the same probability of being chosen.

Comment: Suppose that each positive integer occurred with probability $\frac{1}{100}$.  Is that possible?  Why not?  Extend this to a more general argument.

Comment: I think I understand because you can't have 1/ infinity, right? That was my intuition, but I don't know how to "show" that (and I also wasn't completely sure I was right)

Comment: I suggest ignoring any arguments involving infinity and 1/infinity for the time being, as it seems you know too little about infinity and the nuances in using it to be able to form a coherent argument.  I recommend trying to answer my leading question above, why can't we have each positive integer occur with probability $\frac{1}{100}$?  What explicitly breaks about probability if we allow that?

Comment: Uniform means all have the same probability of occurring, but the set of positive integers is greater than 100. So it wouldn't be possible to have 1 out of 100 chance of choosing something if there is more than 100 objects in the set?

Comment: That is good.  The way I would have phrased it is "*We can't have a probability of $\frac{1}{100}$ for each integer since for example $Pr(\{1,2,3,\dots,101\})=Pr(\{1\})+Pr(\{2\})+\dots+Pr(\{101\})=101\cdot \frac{1}{100}>1$, but no probability may be greater than $1$ causing a contradiction.*"  Now... suppose that $\epsilon$ were some small *strictly positive* real number.  Is it possible for each positive integer to occur with probability $\epsilon$?  The argument will be nearly identical, note that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ would be a finite real number.

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect. Just out of curiosity, what would the argument about infinity be? You're right I don't know enough about infinity to form an argument, but I am curious to know what it would be.

Comment: You would use a limit on the sequence of r.v. that approaches the one you defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that we did have a uniform distribution over the positive integers and suppose that $\epsilon>0$ were a candidate for the probability of a specific positive integer occurring.

But then $Pr(\{1,2,\dots,\lceil \frac{1}{\epsilon}\rceil+1\})\geq \epsilon(\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rceil+1)\geq (1+\epsilon)>1$ yielding a contradiction as no probability may be strictly greater than $1$.

We get then that no strictly positive number may be a candidate for a probability in a uniform distribution.  This does not yet rule out zero probabilities however.

Note though that if our probability were instead zero for each individual positive integer, we would have by [$\sigma$-additivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_additivity#%CF%83-additive_set_functions) (*a required property of probability measures*) that $1 = Pr(\Bbb N) = Pr(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty \{k\}) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty Pr(\{k\}) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty 0 = 0$, another contradiction.

We get as a result that there cannot exist a uniform probability distribution over the positive integers (*and as an almost immediate corollary over any countably infinite set*).

---

Note: $\sigma$-additivity only requires that probabilities of *countable* disjoint unions equals the *countable* sum of probabilities.  When we leave the realm of countable sets and enter the realm of uncountable sets, we can have such things as uniform distributions again, for example the [continuous uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)).

Additional note: Given that $\epsilon>0$ it follows that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ will be finite.  (*You should take the time to prove this if you aren't aware of this property already*).

One might be tempted to let $\epsilon$ be "equal to $\frac{1}{\infty}$" where you might be tempted to say that $\epsilon \neq 0$ and that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}=\infty$.  Such a real number $\epsilon$ would be considered an [infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) different from zero and does not exist in standard real analysis.